# Azure: how to specify 'resource name' in 'Azure Resource Group Deployment task'

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am attempting to follow the instructions in [Franky's Notes](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/03/deploy-automatically-static-website.html), see the video at the bottom.

There is a step to use [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/README.md).

I am getting a name collision. Also the error message may have a bug. Here is the error:

```
2019-08-11T23:52:02.0279313Z ##[error]The resource 'mydemoprojectname' already exists in location 'westus' in resource group 'mydemoprojectname'. A resource with the same name cannot be created in location 'centralus'. Please select a new resource name.
2019-08-11T23:52:02.0284558Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Issue 1: The error says to "*Please select a new resource name.*" There is no field asking for a "*resource name*".

Issue 2: The logs don't represent the request.
It is true that `mydemoprojectname` exists in location 'westus' in a resource group `mydemoprojectname`. I am **not** trying to create a resource in location `centralus`. I am trying to 'create or update' a resource in 'westus'.

Where do I set the "*resource name*" in the *Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action*?

Comment: in the ARM template parameter file ?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT, I ended up tearing down that pipeline and building it a different way. So I wasn't able to verify your answer. I'll upvote because it was useful information.

Answer (score 1):

> Issue 1: The error says to "Please select a new resource name." There
>   is no field asking for a "resource name".

For this issue, I think it is currently not support to rename resources.There is already a user voice about renaming resources . You can vote for this feature here : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/19048513-rename-resources-in-azure-resource-manager-or-powe

```
 ##[error]The resource 'mydemoprojectname' already exists in location 'westus' in resource group 'mydemoprojectname'. A resource with the same name cannot be created in location 'centralus'. Please select a new resource name.
```

For this error, a similar issue has been resolved in this [blog](https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/resolved-appinsights-moved-to-eastus-deployment-failing-with-centralus-message/), please refer to it . You can also refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174774/azure-arm-template-nested-template-deployment-wont-update-resources-fails-to-st) with the similar error. Hope these help.